# how to set font-size in bootstrap to show a constant view?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, font-size

Im getting started Bootstrap but I have problem by Font-size ! 
When I set image  width , like this :

```
width : 15%;
```

for this HTML code :

```
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <header class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <section id="top_nav_bar">
                <img id="avatar" src="img/header/avatar.jpg" title="آقای شجاعی"  />
                <span class="yekan">Dr John Green</span>
            </section>
        </div>
    </header>

</div>
```

when  I open web page by PC(For example 1100px width) , the image portion is  exactly same as when I open web page by a Mobile(For example 500px width)  that s cool ! 
but It does not work for font size !  I set :

```
font-size: 80%;
```

but in Mobile (smaller screen)  Text size's proportion is Bigger that Pc ! 
the proportion is not constant ! 
how can I set it ?
I want to have a responsive-design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vw or vh, these  adjust your font-size by screen width or height.

CSS3 has some new values for sizing things relative to the current viewport size: vw, vh, and vmin. It is relevant to bring up now, because it's shipping in Chrome 20 (canary at the time of this writing). And not behind a flag, it just works. Production usage isn't quite there, but it will be soon enough

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

One unit on any of the three values is 1% of the viewport axis. "Viewport" == browser window size == window object. If the viewport is 40cm wide, 1vw == 0.4cm.